# Chrome Context Menu Child Item functions launching all at once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contextmenu

I am building a chrome extension with context menus. See code below.  It should work as follows: "Connect-It" context item is parent item and shows the two Child items (Add a Link, Add a Doc) in submenu when clicked/hovered. When a specific child item is clicked, a new tab opens a new URL. Instead, if either child item is clicked, both new URl's will open.  Her is my code.  How do I fix this?

```
// background.js

// Parent Level context menu item

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "Connect-IT",  // Required for event pages
    title: "Connect-IT",
    contexts: ["all"],
  });

});

//  child level contextmenu items 

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "Add a Link", 
    parentId: "Connect-IT",
    title: "Add a Link",
    contexts: ["all"],  
 });

});


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "Add a Doc",  
    parentId: "Connect-IT",
    title: "Add a Doc",
    contexts: ["all"],  
 });

});

// click handler below.  This is what's broken.  If either Child Menu Item is clicked both of the function below execute
//     launching the two web pages.  If one menu item is clicked only the website with taht item shoudl launch.


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function addLink(info){     menuItemId="Add a Link",
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.wufoo.com"});
})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function addDoc(info){  menuItemId="Add a Doc",
    chrome.tabs.create( {url: "https://www.google.com"});
})
```

Comment: isn't the signature chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tabs){})

Comment: I tried adding ", tabs" as suggested but that did not work. To be clear, the functions launch, they just both launch upon any menuItemId click event, instead of just when their menuItemId is clicked.

Comment: I didn't suggest adding tabs, I just queried your use of  'function addDoc(info)' or 'function addLink(info)' rather than the more straight forward  function(info, tabs). Also what has been clicked is passed into that function in Info. (so info.id will be either "Add a Link" or "Add a Doc" and then you take the appropriate action based on values passed in. Don't you only need one listener. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

Comment: I guess that's where I am confused.I am only a beginning programmer.  Can't seem to figure out the code to make the one addListener invoke only the appropriate function from the item that is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace these two statements

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function addLink(info){     menuItemId="Add a Link",
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.wufoo.com"});
})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function addDoc(info){  menuItemId="Add a Doc",
  chrome.tabs.create( {url: "https://www.google.com"});
})
```

with this single statement

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tabs){  
  if ( info.menuItemId === 'Add a Link' )
    chrome.tabs.create( {url: "https://www.google.com"});
  else 
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.wufoo.com"});
});
```

Comment: I tried that function.  result is that only the "else" part works.  Wufoo is launched when either menu item is clicked.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: OK, great news, I would now strongly suggest that you  DEBUG the application and see what values are being passed in via info and then set the appropriate if condition to get the desired effect in each case. A simple console.log(info); at the top of the function will do the trick.......

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I changed "info.id" to "info.menuItemId" and it works.

Comment: So, so I've updated the answer to show that - can you accept the answer as correct?